# Log.txt of an unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: c#, logging, try-catch, invalidoperationexception

I am currently working on a way to `log` into a text file an `exception error` of type `System.InvalidOPerationException` via a `try{}... catch{}` block. My concern is that `Log.txt` outputs:

> Message :Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
>   StackTrace :
>   Date :4/21/2016 9:50:42 AM

Ideally I'd like it to be a bit *more informative* on the nature of the exception such those revealed by `Microsoft Visual Studio dialog box`. As an illustration:

> An unhandled exception of type `System.InvalidOPerationException` occured
>       inSystem.dll
>       Additional information: the given ColumnName .... does not match up with
>       any column in datasource

see below the `try....catch` block applied on my method:

**EDIT**

```
try
{
// call method
}

catch (InvalidOperationException exc)
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(logPath, true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("Message :" + exc.Message + "<br/>" +   
            Environment.NewLine + "StackTrace :" + exc.StackTrace +
            "" + Environment.NewLine + "Date :" +  
            DateTime.Now.ToString());
        writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------"
            + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Any relevant idea would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use `ex.ToString()`, this will give you  Message and StackTrace of exception. On a side note: try using a well known logging library instead of writing your own. [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html) is a superp library for logging in .net.

Comment: Also, look for InnerExceptions.

Comment: @raidensan: thanks for the sharing `log4net`.

Comment: @stuartd: I've edited the above code with the correction, but thanks.